# How can I check if the first command on a pipe gets an error?

Tags: pipe, error-handling

Let's say I execute the following command on a terminal:

```
this-command-doesnt-exist-and-closes-with-code-127 | jq ''
```

If I execute `echo $?` I'll get `0` as result because it's checking the exit code from `jq`. I'd like to know the exit code from the first command on the pipe. I thought about redirecting the stderr like:

```
this-command-doesnt-exist-and-closes-with-1 2>&1 | jq ''
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "I got an error"
fi
```

Just so I send a message that doesn't make sense to `jq`. It'd solve the problem but it doesn't look like the right solution for it. How can I manage getting the error code of commands on pipes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `bash` you can use `set -o pipefail`:

```
$ set -o pipefail
$ this-command-doesnt-exist-and-closes-with-code-127 | jq ''
bash: this-command-doesnt-exist-and-closes-with-code-127: command not found...
$ echo $?
127
```

From [bash man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> pipefail
>
> If set, the return value of a pipeline is the value of the last (rightmost)
> command  to  exit  with  a  non-zero status, or zero if all commands in the
> pipeline exit successfully.  This option is disabled by default.

Comment: +1.  There's also the PIPESTATUS array in bash, which contains the list of exit status values from commands in the most-recently-executed pipeline.  There are [several questions and answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=PIPESTATUS) on this site about it.